# event notification for documentDB instances

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-documentdb

I get an alert like this everytime I create / delete a documentDB instance. I do not remember how did I set it up. I checked documentDB console as well as cloudwatch console, but can not see any relveant entry.

```
Event Source : db-instance
Identifier Link: https://console.aws.amazon.com/docdb/home?region=us-east-1#dbinstance:id=docdb-2019-08-30-10-48-09
SourceId: docdb-2019-08-30-10-48-09
Notification time : 2019-08-30 10:58:10.508
Message : DB instance created
Event ID : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondocdb/latest/developerguide/events.html#RDS-EVENT-0005
```

Anyone can guide me how to get a notification like this for documentDB instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is RDS instance alert created in cloudwatch - Events - Rules.

[image]

If you have created the alert as a "root" user, you can not view / modify it using IAM user who usually has limited privileges!